# How to delete data in ArrayList using a for loop

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm deleting my `ArrayList` data using for loop but the loop only deletes the last index of my list. What's wrong with this? I think this would be easy but I'm taking an hour an still cannot solve this.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowFile.size() - 1; i++) {
     imagesFileName.remove(i);
         mylist.remove(i);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"" + selectedRowFile.size() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Use iterator! This is not safe..

Comment: Can you give me an example i don't know what iterator is. Although I'm new to java

Answer (score 4):

You should remove an element from a List using an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

```
        Iterator<YourDataType> it = YourList.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) 
               it.remove();
```

With this you can use if-else to specify the element, which should be removed.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection) should give you some hints, why you should use an Iterator.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you're using a for loop, but you can also clear an `ArrayList` object by using clear.

```
List myList = new ArrayList<Object>();
myList.clear();
```

Using a for loop to clear an `ArrayList` seems dubious to me.

Comment: I want to use for loop because im not going to delete all the data in my array list

Comment: Then your best chances are to follow the answer that Steve Benett gave you